# 'this' is not right in js class methods

Tags: javascript

I am writing 'class' like func in js. For those private methods, I want to hide it away, instead of prefix with '_' and sit inside the func protoype.

So what I do is to write those private funcs outside of the class/func definition.

The only problem now is how to invoke that method.

1. `this.somePrivateMethods` will not work, since those on not in the class definition
2. `somePrivateMethods.call(this, arg1, arg2)` is working as expected. But it seems too hacky?

Wonder why simply calling `somePrivateMethods()` inside another class method will have `window` in the context?

What do you guys do about this?

```js
window.name = 'window name';

var A = function(){
  this.name = 'A name';
}

A.prototype.publicMethod = function(){
  
  //this is working, but the method is attach to the prototype, and outsider can invoke that method accidentally
  this._privateMethod();
  
  //this is not working
  _privateMethod2();
  
  //this works, outsider cannot call the private method, but the syntax doesn't look good.
  _privateMethod2.call(this);
  
  
  function _privateMethod2() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
  
}

A.prototype._privateMethod = function() {
  console.log(this.name);
}


var a = new A();
a.publicMethod();
```

Comment: *"Wonder why simply calling somePrivateMethods() inside another class method will have window in the context?"* - Because that's [how `this` works in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)? I'd create the class inside an IIFE that returns the constructor, so then only methods exposed deliberately on the prototype would be accessible to other code, and I'd use `.call()` and/or `.apply()` to call any private functions where the value of `this` needs to be set.

Comment: thx. and what normally do you do with the private methods?

Comment: Short of using `.apply`, `.call`, `.bind` or lexically-scoped lambdas, `this` is whatever is on the left-hand side of the dot, when you call the function (at the moment you call it).
If there is no dot (and you haven't used the aforementioned methods), then `this` is either going to be `window` or `undefined`, depending on whether you're using strict mode or not.

Comment: If you define the function inside of another it will be scoped to the function it's inside. Just don't use `this` when defining the function.

Comment: @nnnnnn, so you are saying '_privateMethod2.call(this);' is the right thing to do if we hide the private methods? There're just a lots of them, does not look pretty (to me, at least:)

Comment: to @Norguard, thx, you explained it very clear

Comment: to @PHPglue, I've updated the questions, it not true that inner func has outter scope. see second line of outcome

Comment: With the code in the current version of your question, you can create a local variable `var _this = this;` and then within `_privateMethod2()` use `_this` instead of `this`, and then just call `_privateMethod2()` directly without using dot method syntax or `.call()`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrrdgo?editors=0011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `var` within your Constructor, or simply define the function inside it, without making it a property.

```
var fakeStaticVar = 'Everything below can inherit';
function YourConstructor(){
  var privateVar = 'Notice the first bunch of console.log()s';
  this.publicProp = 'This will be public';
  this.setPrivateVar = function(str){
    privateVar = str;
  }
  this.getPrivateVar = function(){
    return privateVar;
  }
  this.setPublicProp = function(str){
    this.publicProp = str;
  }
  this.getPublicProp = function(){
    return this.publicProp;
  }
  function privateFunc(str){
    privateVar = str;
  }
  this.executePrivateFunc = function(str){
    privateFunc(str);
    return privateVar; // returns as well - for testing
  }
  this.setFakeStaticVar = function(str){
    fakeStaticVar = str;
  }
  this.getFakeStaticVar = function(){
    return fakeStaticVar;
  }
}
var privateVar = 'Not the same as the privateVar in YourConstructor';
function privateFunc(){
  return 'Not the same as the one in privateFunc in YourConstructor';
}
var yc = new YourConstructor; console.log(yc.privateVar);
console.log(privateVar); yc.setPrivateVar('cool');
console.log(privateVar); console.log(yc.privateVar);
console.log(yc.getPrivateVar()); yc.publicProp = 'now';
console.log(yc.getPublicProp()); console.log(yc.publicProp);
yc.setPublicProp("you're learning"); console.log(yc.getPublicProp());
console.log(privateFunc()); console.log(yc.privateFunc);
yc.executePrivateFunc('neat'); console.log(yc.getPrivateVar());
yc.setFakeStaticVar('Awesome'); 
var nc = new YourConstructor; console.log(nc.getFakeStaticVar());
```

Hope this helps. Note `YourConstrutor` has no arguments, so it's okay to leave off `()` when creating a `new` instance.

Although, there is no such thing as a static property in JavaScript, this behavior can also mimicked using `prototype`:

```
function A(){
  this.test = 'rad';
}
var a = new A;
a.newProp = 'new prop value';
console.log(a.newProp);
var b = new A;
console.log(b.newProp); // undefined
```

Now try this:

```
function A(){
  this.test = 'rad';
}
var a = new A;
A.prototype.newProp = 'new prop value';
console.log(a.newProp);
var b = new A;
console.log(b.newProp);
```

For an internal static property you can use `this.constructor.prototype` inside your Constructor:

```
function C(value){
  this.notStaticProp = value;
  this.setStaticProp = function(prop, val){
    this.constructor.prototype[prop] = val; // static
  }
}
var a = new C('any value here');
console.log(a.notStaticProp);
a.setStaticProp('wow', 'it works'); // sets static property
var b = new C('different value');
console.log(b.notStaticProp);
console.log(b.wow);
```

Here's yet another way to create a sort of static var:

```
var counter = (function(){
  var c = 0;
  return function(){
    return ++c;
  }
})();
console.log(counter()); console.log(counter());
```

It's all about the scope. Note: when `var` is used, when defining a function or Constructor, you cannot call it above its definition. When `var` is not use you can call or make a `new` instance anywhere.

Comment: Thanks you get much for the detail explained. I like the idea of just var instead of this, just need to change my habit of typing this. before accessing the variables

Comment: `this` can be confusing at first, but you'll learn to love it. It really belongs to the `new` instance in this case.